# Braintree push notification is not working

Tags: php, push-notification, webhooks, braintree

I have used the Sandbox account of Braintree for recurring subscriptions. The verification of the webhook end URL is succeeded.But I didn't get any push notifications to my server even after successful completion of the subscription. I am using PHP environment to fetch the POST details. Below is the code segment I have used.

```
<?php

require_once(app_classes.'DB.Class.php');
require_once(app_classes.'util.Class.php');
require_once app_classes.'braintree/lib/Braintree.php';
Braintree_Configuration::environment(bt_environment);
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId(bt_merchant_id);
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey(bt_public_key);
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey(bt_private_key);

if(
     isset($_POST["bt_signature"]) &&
     isset($_POST["bt_payload"])
) {
    $webhookNotification = Braintree_WebhookNotification::parse(
        $_POST["bt_signature"], $_POST["bt_payload"]
);

$message =    "[Webhook Received " . $webhookNotification->timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "] "
        . "Kind: " . $webhookNotification->kind . " | "
                . "Subscription: " . $webhookNotification->subscription->id . "\n";

$subDetails = array( 'data' => $message );
DB::insert('subscription_notifications', $subDetails);
}
return 200;
?>
```

The server has SSL certificate. Please let me know if any thing I need to do to get it working.

Comment: @agf. can you help me with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. This was the issue related with SSL certificate. The connection get closed with an HTTP status of 599 for all the attempts to POST. This is happened because of the intermediate certificate was missing in the server. We added the certificate .Now I can access the push notifications from Braintree.